# making a high score board from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to make a highscore board so it sorts and prints out the top scores and what user achieved them.
I have got these in a list `['tim - 8','jim - 12','terry - 18','frank - 14']`
and i am trying to make it print like:

```
HIGHSCORES
terry - 18
frank - 14
jim - 12
tim - 8
```

Whats the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a (`lambda`) function to `split` the part after the `-` and convert it to `int`, then use that function as the `key` to `sort` the list in `reverse`.

```
scores = ['tim - 8','jim - 12','terry - 18','frank - 14']
scores.sort(key=lambda s: int(s.split("-")[1]), reverse=True)
# ['terry - 18', 'frank - 14', 'jim - 12', 'tim - 8']
```